# How to write a database adapter for ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm a newbie to Rails and I must connect to a customised postgresql , which has some system tables changed. when using the default postgres adapter, it will throw the following errors:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pg_type" does not exist
LINE 2:               FROM pg_type as t
                           ^
:               SELECT t.oid, t.typname, t.typelem, t.typdelim,t.typinput, r.rngsubtype, t.typtype, t.typbasetype
          FROM pg_type as t
          LEFT JOIN pg_range as r ON oid = rngtypid

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pg_type" does not exist
LINE 2:               FROM pg_type as t
                           ^
:               SELECT t.oid, t.typname, t.typelem, t.typdelim,t.typinput, r.rngsubtype, t.typtype, t.typbasetype
                FROM pg_type as t
          LEFT JOIN pg_range as r ON oid = rngtypid
```

these sys-table start with 'pg_' have changed !

So I must create a new **adapter** for the creepy database.
Are there any tutorials or guides can follow ?

Comment: What is changed in this custom database? Do the system tables have different structures, or just different names?

Comment: just change the names. so if i change some method of the module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::SchemaStatements
i can fix it . But maybe i must post another question about how to write a monkey patch for ActiveRecord properly

Comment: Run `CREATE VIEW pg_type AS SELECT * FROM custom_pg_type` on the database. Repeat for the other renamed tables. The standard Postgres adapter should now work.

Comment: it not practical for my situation . my app is a database tool that user can create a  connection to any database like that .  it's impossible to run a sql file and create views  needed

Comment: OK. It looks like you will need to customise a few files from [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters) and possibly [here](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg). I don't know Ruby, so that's about all I can tell you...